# Undefined result from Fizz Buzz game Javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, for-loop

I'm having an assignment where I have to do the FizzBuzz game in Javascript. The problem is I get 'Answer = undefined' when I run the function. I have to print it with a comma separated value but I think I can figure that out for my self though; Thanks in advance. Regards, Thomas.

```
function fizzBuzz(start, stop) {

    for(var i = start; i <= stop; i++) {
        if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0) {
            document.write("Fizz Buzz");
        }else if(i % 3 == 0) {
            document.write("Fizz");
        }else if(i % 5 == 0) {
            document.write("Buzz");
        }else {
            document.write(i);
        }
    }
}

ANSWER = (fizzBuzz(4, 22));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't returning anything from your function.

ANSWER will be what you 'return' in a function.

If you wanted to return all the values you would need to do somthing like

```
var ans='';

...
```

if ( whatever)  ans+= 'Fizz Buzz,';

```
....

return ans.substring(0,ans.length-1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the `fizzBuzz` function isn't returning anything. You need to return a result from that function. `document.write` writes out text to the document.

Answer (score 1):

Some modifications to your code...

```
function fizzBuzz(start, stop) {
    var i;
    var results = [];
    for (i = start; i <= stop; i++) {
        if (i % 15 == 0) {
            results.push('Fizz Buzz');
        } else if (i % 3 == 0) {
            results.push('Fizz');
        } else if (i % 5 == 0) {
            results.push('Buzz');
        } else {
            // cast to string just so all the results in the array are string
            results.push(i + '');
        }
    }
    return results;
}

ANSWER = fizzBuzz(4, 22);  // output: [ '4', 'Fizz', 'Buzz', '7', '8', ...etc ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<script>
function fizzBuzz(start, stop) {
  var str = 'ANSWER = ';
    for(var i = start; i <= stop; i++) {
        if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0) {
            str += "Fizz Buzz";
        }else if(i % 3 == 0) {
            str += "Fizz";
        }else if(i % 5 == 0) {
            str += "Buzz";
        }else {
            str += i;
        }
        if (i<stop)
            str += ", ";

    }
    document.getElementById('writeto').innerHTML += str;
}
fizzBuzz(4, 22);
</script>
<body>
  <a id='writeto'></a>
</body>
</html>
```